# Why aren't sprites in Pygame blitting to the screen in Windows 7?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been working on a Space Invaders-type game for the past week or so, and it's coming along really well, but for some reason when I run the game on my Windows computer (the one I prefer to code on), most of the sprites don't show up, or only show up when they're moving in a certain direction on the screen. When I run the exact same code on my Mac, everything blits and updates perfectly. Is this a known issue that pygame just doesn't get along with Windows? The fact that everything works on my Mac makes me think that it's not an issue with my code, but just in case, here's my main loop:

```
dirty = []
score_label = font.render("Score: " + str(score), 1, (255,215,0))
level_label = font.render("Level: " + str(level), 1, (255,215,0))
screen.blit(background,(10,10),(10,10,330,30))
screen.blit(score_label,(10,10))
screen.blit(level_label,(200,10))
dirty.append((10,10,330,30))

# New level
if isEmpty(enemies):
    dirty.append((400,300,150,30))
    for i in bullets:
        dirty.append(i.pos)
        screen.blit(background,(i.pos[0],i.pos[1]),i.pos)
        bullets.remove(i)
    if pauseCounter == 40:
        screen.blit(background,(400,300),(400,300,150,30))
        pauseCounter = 0 
        jump = 30
        level+=1    
        for x in range(1,6):
            for y in range(11):
                enemies[x-1].append(Sprites.Enemy(enemy_values[6-x],(60*y,40*x),6-x))
        for x in range(len(enemies)):
            for e in enemies[x]:
                dirty.append(e.pos)
    else:
        upLevelLabel = levelFont.render("Next Level!",1,(255,215,0))
        screen.blit(upLevelLabel,(400,300))
        pauseCounter += 1

# Player input
dirty.append(o.pos)
screen.blit(background,(o.pos[0],o.pos[1]),o.pos)
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[K_a] and o.pos[0]-10 >= 0:
    o.speed = -10
    o.move()
if keys[K_d] and o.pos[0] <= 907-o.pos[3]-10:
    o.speed = 10
    o.move()
dirty.append(o.pos)
screen.blit(o.image,o.pos)

# Add bullets
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_SPACE:
            bullets.append(Sprites.Bullet(bullet,(o.pos[0]+28,o.pos[1])))

# Updates bunkers
for b in bunkers:
    screen.blit(b.image,b.pos)
    if b.health == 0:
        screen.blit(background,(b.pos[0],b.pos[1]),b.pos)
        dirty.append(b.pos)
        bunkers.remove(b)

# Check if bullets are offscreen/collide, move accordingly
for b in bullets:
    dirty.append(b.pos)
    if b.pos[1] < 0:
        screen.blit(background,(b.pos[0],b.pos[1]),b.pos)
        dirty.append(b.pos)
        bullets.remove(b) 
    if isEmpty(enemies) == False:
        for x in range(len(enemies)):
            if len(enemies[x]) > 0:
                temp = enemies[x][0]
                if b.pos[1] in range(temp.pos[1],temp.pos[1]+temp.pos[3]):
                    for e in enemies[x]:
                        if b.pos.colliderect(e.pos):
                            score += e.val*10
                            screen.blit(background,(b.pos[0],b.pos[1]),b.pos)
                            screen.blit(background,(e.pos[0],e.pos[1]),e.pos)
                            dirty.append(e.pos)
                            dirty.append(b.pos)
                            bullets.remove(b)
                            enemies[x].remove(e)
    for i in bunkers:
        if b.pos.colliderect(i.pos):
            screen.blit(background,(b.pos[0],b.pos[1]),b.pos)
            dirty.append(b.pos)
            i.health -= 1
            bullets.remove(b)
for b in bullets:
    dirty.append(b.pos)
    screen.blit(background,(b.pos[0],b.pos[1]),b.pos)
    b.move()
    screen.blit(b.image,b.pos)
    dirty.append(b.pos)

# Moves enemy at appropriate pace, drops bombs
if enemyMoves == jump:
    moveCounter += 1
    if moveCounter == 20:
        jump = jump/2
        moveCounter = 0
    enemyMoves = 0
    for x in range(len(enemies)):
        for e in enemies[x]:
            dirty.append(e.pos)
            screen.blit(background,(e.pos[0],e.pos[1]),e.pos)
            e.move()
            screen.blit(e.image,e.pos)
            dirty.append(e.pos)
else:
    for x in range(len(enemies)):
        for e in enemies[x]:
            screen.blit(e.image,e.pos)
    enemyMoves+=1

pygame.display.update(dirty)
clock.tick(30)
print clock.get_fps()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd like to see more code showing the full start to finish of blitting stuff to the screen along with the `pygame.display.update();`

Comment: In small game I wouldn't bother to update screen partially - I would redraw all screen. Maybe Windows has problem with partial update.

Comment: What is the "certain direction" that you mention?

Comment: I was redrawing the entire screen originally, but that was causing me to max out at 17 FPS on my laptop, so I changed to partial and was able to get the 30 which it's designed to have. But that could be it, because I think it was after that change that I started having the problem.

@SimonT The aliens move back and forth horizontally, and when they are moving right only the far row appears, but when they move left they all appear.

Comment: Try drawing a hollow rectangle on the display surface over every Rect in `dirty`, and see if the game is indeed redrawing in the correct _locations_.  Or there might be an issue with erasing every column except the last one, because something is wrong with your erase/move/redraw logic.

Comment: I tried the blank rectangle thing and the locations are right, which makes sense because everything looks completely fine when I run the exact same code on OS X. I'm fairly certain that the dirty rectangle update method is what's causing the problem, because I started having this issue around the time I started using that update method. Thanks everyone for all your help, I just need to figure out if there's a way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try:

```
dirty.append(Rect(x,y,width,height))
```

or

```
dirty.append(pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height))
```

Remember, you are passing a rectangle list to `pygame.display.update(dirty)` and so try and stick to pygame rectangles

instead of:

```
dirty.append((x,y,width,height))
```

Comment: There's only one instance where I pass just coordinates instead a Rectangle, and it's not one of the elements that's not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to furas, it was the partial update that was causing the error!